# Are people in this community interested in having a new site for other Geospatial technologies?

Tags: discussion, scope

Regarding [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/remote-sensing-in-geoscience) that took place about 1 year ago and considering all the comments, I want to have a similar discussion here which is the closest community to RS.
I think that remote sensing cannot be covered with GIS + Earth science and I have given some reasons [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4019/19874), [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21707/142064) and [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21610/142064)
If you don't have time to study the reasons, I just say that probably there are some geodesists, photogrammetrists, remote sensing experts who attend in this community and most of GIS experts are somehow familiar with RS, Geodesy, Photogrammetry, Surveying , GPS ,etc that are totally called geomatics,geoinformatics or geospatial tools, so there's no need to make you familiar
Also as the members of this site, you know that sometime remote sensing or geodesy related questionS don't get a proper comprehensive answer in this community

**So are you interested in having a new site?**

**If yes, What do you want the proposal of the site be named?**

**Will I have the support of some members of this community if I make a proposal for a new site or change the name of the current proposal?**

**If yes, which percent you think will commit in the new site?**

I just beg you that participate in the discussion. Even a small comment will be considered. I'm really confused about the name of the proposal and have doubt that do we really need a new site or not?

(Note that [a similar question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/are-people-in-this-community-interested-in-having-a-new-site-for-other-geospatia) was asked in Cross Validated.)

**Also a chat room has been created** http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that, in time, there will be enough Remote Sensing questions posted here at GIS SE and at other sites (about which I cannot comment), for it to bud off as a specialist community.

However, from past discussions here I suspect that you will struggle to get the critical mass to make such a site sustainable just yet:

- [Area 51 - Remote Sensing - Any one interested in supporting this?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/area-51-remote-sensing-any-one-interested-in-supporting-this)
- [Should FAQ include reference to Remote Sensing, Image Processing and/or Surveying?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/should-faq-include-reference-to-remote-sensing-image-processing-and-or-surveyin)

Your Area 51 proposal seems to take two forms:

- In principle I would support a separate Remote Sensing site, but in practice I suspect it remains unsustainable for now.
- I would oppose a renaming from GIS to Geomatics because I think it would be counter-productive to do so when such a large percentage (I do not know numbers) of its users appear to have been calling what they do GIS, since they started doing it i.e. it already has the mindshare and branding that is critical to site success.

Comment: GIS is much broader than Geomatics in 25 Years of Experience, Geomatics is used quite heavily in North America. Remote Sensing is accepted here as questions. The same could be said about Earth Science http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ in beta